# divs with images always get on the top of divs with text when I randomize their position (on load and using setInterval). JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, setinterval

When I randomize position of some divs with text and some others with images (on load and using setInterval), images always get on the top of the divs with text. I’ve been trying to find a solution by myself but I just started learning how to code a few weeks ago, and I don’t even know what am I looking for. So I’d appreciate if someone could help me. This is my code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div{
                position: absolute;
            }
            .description{
                width: 650px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Init(){
                divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
                setInterval (mover, 500);
            }

            function mover(){
                divs.forEach(div => {
                    var spaceH =window.innerHeight - div.clientHeight;
                    var spaceW =window.innerWidth - div.clientWidth;
                    div.style.top=Math.round(Math.random()* spaceH) + "px";
                    div.style.left=Math.round(Math.random()* spaceW) + "px";
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Init()">
        <div class="description">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </div>
        <div><img src="MyImage1.jpg" class="imagenes" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="MyImage2.jpg" class="imagenes" alt=""></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I intend to doit with many divs more. This is just a test. And sorry if I’m not explaining myself properly.

Comment: If div 1 is rendered after div 2, div 1 will overlay div 2. It's not dependent on what the div content is (image or text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one div is rendered after another, it will overlay the prior div. It doesn't matter if the div contains text or an image. The newer div will still overlay the older div.

Example:

```css
.overlay {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  Here is a div with text. Lots and lots.
</div>
<div class="overlay" style="left: 40px; top: 40px">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/80" style="width: 80px; height: 80px">
</div>
<div class="overlay" style="left: 80px; top: 20px">
  Here is a div with text. Lots and lots.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. And would you happen to know a way to render all at once or something like that to stop this?

Comment: There's no way to render all divs at once, they will render in the order they exist. But you can change which ones overlay by setting `style="z-index"` on the div. A div with a higher z-index will overlay one with a lower z-index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check that.